# How to get data from wordpress post table when made my own rows

Tags: php, wordpress

### Heading

Ive setup my wordpress website fine, but i have made some extra rows in the wp-post table in my database. i have added a row called "periode" but i dont know how to display that row when sitting in dreamweaver.

im using

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

            <?php the_content(); ?>

            <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => 'Pages: ', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>

        <?php edit_post_link('Edit this entry.', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

and i want to dispay the row data of "periode" between the title and the content. does any1 know any php code to get tha info to the single page?

Comment: why in the world did you create an extra row in the posts table?

Comment: Yes, bad move, you should use post meta for extra info about each post.

Comment: When you say 'extra rows', do you mean columns?

Answer (score 1):

Well you have to use post meta for any more info, But if you want to to that then here is complete way to obtain data from sql to display.

Required: Server running PHP and MySQL. If youÂ are not using or testing via the web, you will need to install WAMP on your PC, enable Apache on your mac, or install Apache on your Linux machine.
Skills needed:

**Creating a MySQL database and table
 basic HTML:
 creating forms and form elements
 basic PHP:
 creating variables
 echo statements**

We will explore this topic by creating a real world application. Our goal will be to access a MySQL database of vehicles (cars), dynamically choosing them by their make and/or their for sale/lease availability.
Create your MySQL database

You should already be familiar with creating a MySQL databse on your server. Please refer to other tutorials and references for specific help. A good source of info is w3schools.com.

Name your database 'myDatabase' or whatever else you choose to name it. Keep track of the username used to set this databse up, as well as the password used. You will also need the server name which is often localhost, but that vaires depending on your server/webhost. Check with their documentation if you are uncertain.
Create a new table

Create a new table inside this database. Name it vehicles or whatever else you choose to name it. For now, create a table with 5 fields and 7 rows. I created the 5 fields like this:

```
field: increment, Type: int(1), Extra: auto_increment, Primary Key
field: make, Type: varchar(15), Index
field: model, Type: varchar(15)
field: year, Type: year(4)
field: availability, Type: varchar(5), Index
```

The 'make' and 'availability' fields are Indexed, to make searching them more efficient. For a table this size, it doesn't matter much, but for a large table it can help the performance.
Insert data into the fields. For this example, my table looks like this:

**increment        make        model        year        availability**
1                          ford          fiesta           2011           sale
2                              ford            mustang             2011            sale
3                              ford            mustang             2010            lease
4                              ford            fiesta          2010            lease
5                              chevy           volt            2011            sale
6                              chevy           volt            2011            lease
7                         chevy             volt            2010            lease

**Create your web page**

Create, name and save a web page as .html or .php, whichever you prefer. This page will contain a form with radio buttons which will allow the user to narrow down their search of cars, based on either the make (ford or chevy, in this example) and/or the availability (whether vehicle is for sale or lease).
Create a form with radio buttons

This will be a simple form, with 2 radio button groups - 1 to choose vehicle make, and the other to choose vehicle availability. The form will have a submit button which will have as its action to post to a php page 'vehicles.php'. You can style it as you want with CSS. Here is the code:

```
<form name="input" action="vehicles.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Make you are looking for:</legend>
<input type="radio" name="make" value="ford" /> Ford
<input type="radio" name="make" value="chevy" /> Chevy
<input type="radio" name="make" value="all" checked /> All
</fieldset>
<fieldset>   
<legend>Looking to:</legend>    
<input type="radio" name="availability" value="sale" /> Buy
<input type="radio" name="availability" value="lease" /> Rent 
<input type="radio" name="availability" value="all" checked /> All 
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />   
</form>
```

Let's look at the form

This submitted form will send values to and trigger the file 'vehicles.php'. This is the file which will process the items clicked on this form, and will query the MySQL database to return the requested information.

The first radio button group is named 'make' to correspond to the same field in the database table, with the possible the values to choose from being the same as the data in the 'make' field of the database table. In other words, since we have the data as 'ford' and 'chevy' in the database, we then use those same case sensitive values for the buttons. The 'All' button has the value 'all' and is a special case, as we'll see later on.
  The second radio button group is named 'availability' to correspond to the same filed in the database table, and the values the same as the data in the 'availability' field of the database table ( 'sale', 'lease', and the special case 'all').

Since this form will post to 'vehicles.php', let's create that next.
The PHP file

Create a new empty php file and name it 'vehicles.php'. This page/file needs to accomplish several things:

receive the values from the radio buttons
 connect to the database
 query the database based on the values passed from the radio buttons
 print out the correct information

Writing the PHP

In order to access the database, we need the username, password, database name, server name, and database table name. Let's start out by placing the username, password, and database name into php variables:

```
$username="myUserName";
$password="myPassWord";
$database="myDatabaseName";
```

We can make this a lit bit more secure by placing this information in it's own separate php file, named for instance 'config.php'. We then access it by including or requiring it in the main php file. If placed outside your root folder, it adds another layer of security.

```
ob_start();
require("config.php");
ob_end_clean();
```

Wrapped inside commands to start, and then end and erase(clean) the output buffering (ob), we also increase some security issues. Please consult PHP resources to best address your security needs.
Create some variables for requests

I would next create some variables to use as requests. These will be the values that are sent from the form's 2 radio button groups. So the first one, '$req' will be equal to the value we get from the 'make' button group. The second one, $req2' will be equal to the value obtained from the 'availability' radio button group.

```
$req=$_REQUEST['make'];
$req2=$_REQUEST['availability'];
```

Conenct to the database

We can next connect to the database. Any connection that is opened must at some point be closed! If you need to brush up on this or other specifics of PHP, please consult other PHP documentation and manuals.

```
mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
```

"localhost" is the name of the server where the database is located. This will vary depending on your server. Many servers have it located as 'localhost'. Others will be a specific address such as 'sql28e8d34f.carrierzone.com' or something else. Please consult your web host or server administrator for your specific settings.

If there is a problem connecting, you will see the message "Unable to select database".
Choose which table to work from

In a simple scenario, you would just state which database table to work in. In our case, we are working from the 'vehicles' table. The simple code to select ( go through every row) of this table would look like this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM vehicles";
```

What we want to do is a little more complicated than that. Let's review. We want to first see which 'make' was chosen. If 'ford' was chosen, we want to only consider the rows which have the 'make' field filled in as 'ford'. Likewise if 'chevy' was chosen, we only want to choose 'make' fields with a value of 'chevy'. But if 'all' is chosen, then we DO want to consider all rows.

Similarly, if the 'buy' or 'lease' button was chosen we only want to be shown rows which are either 'buy' or lease', and if 'all' was chosen, then we want to consider all rows.

Choosing from just one field is fairly simple too. For instance, to consider only rows of 'ford, we can can ask our query to SELECT all rows FROM the vehicles table WHERE the field 'make' is 'ford'. That would look like this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE make='ford'";
```

Since we don't know which 'make' will be chosen, we can't hard code the value. We want to use the value that was passed from the button chosen in the form. Remember that we stored this value as '$req', so now we can make this query as:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE make='$req'";
```

Not so bad. But since we want to check both the make AND the availability, we can use a query which uses '$req' to look for 'make' and '$req2' to look for availability:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE make='$req' AND availability='$req2'";
```

OK. Still not so bad. But now what happens if one or both of the buttons were chosen for 'all'? Basically, with these 2 radio button groups there are 4 different scenarios that could happen:

a particular make was chosen and a particular availability was chosen
 'all' was chosen for 'make', and a particular availability was chosen
 a particular make was chosen, and 'all' was chosen for 'availability'
 'all' was chosen for both 'make' and 'availability'

There are probably other ways to handle this. I choose to do this as a series of 'if/else' conditionals. Here is the code to handle the 4 conditions:

```
if ($req!="all" && $req2!="all")  $query="SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE make='$req' AND availability='$req2'";
else if($req=="all" && $req2!="all" ) $query="SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE availability='$req2'";
else if($req!="all" && $req2=="all" ) $query="SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE make='$req'";
else if($req=="all" || $req2=="all" ) $query="SELECT * FROM vehicles";
```

You might notice that all of these conditions are really just checking whether a value was set as 'all':

```
if(&req=='all')
```

or whether it was set as something else(and therefore it does NOT equal 'all'):

```
if(&req!='all')
```

Finish the query and close the connection

These following 4 lines of standard code are used to finish the query and to close the connection. From it, we learn both which rows contain the information we asked for which is stored in the variable '$result', as well as the number of rows this information is in, which is stored in the variable '$num'. Also, note that the connection is now closed. Consult PHP manuals for further discussion.

```
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
mysql_query($result);
mysql_close();
```

Using this information

We can now actually use this information! What we need to do is to iterate(loop through) the rows that contained the requested data, and to print this out ('echo' it, in php lingo). We will use a 'for' loop to accomplish this. You will see others using 'while' loops to do this. Depending on the case at hand, the differences between the 2 can be subtle or profound. In this case it doesn't matter, so either would work.

```
$i=0;
for ($i; $i < $num; $i++){
$f12=mysql_result($result,$i,"model");
$f13=mysql_result($result,$i,"year");
$f14=mysql_result($result,$i,"availability");
```

Note that in the opening curly bracket in line 2 is not closed yet. It will be closed shortly.
Explanation

a variable '$i' is created and it's initial value is set to the integer zero.
 the 'for' loop begins at $i equaling zero, and continues while $i is less than the value of '$num', which is the number of correct rows from the query. After each iteration, $i is increased by 1($i++).
 variable $f12 is set at the value of 'model' in the row of the query with the value $i.
 variable $f13 is set at the value of 'year' in the row of the query with the value $i.
 variable $f14 is set at the value of 'availability' in the row of the query with the value $i.

Print this to the page

All that is left to do is to print this info to the page. We'll do this by concatenating (combining) the 3 variables, including spaces between each, and adding a line break after the 3rd variable. The second line of code closes the 'for' loop with a closing curly bracket.

```
echo $f12." ".$f13." ".$f14." ";
}
```

Here is the complete html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="input" action="vehicles.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Make you are looking for:</legend>
<input type="radio" name="make" value="ford" /> Ford
<input type="radio" name="make" value="chevy" /> Chevy
<input type="radio" name="make" value="all" checked /> All
</fieldset>
<fieldset>   
<legend>Looking to:</legend>    
<input type="radio" name="availability" value="sale" /> Buy
<input type="radio" name="availability" value="lease" /> Lease 
<input type="radio" name="availability" value="all" checked /> All 
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />   
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the complete code for 'vehicle.php'

```
<?php
ob_start();
require("config.php");
ob_end_clean();

$req=$_REQUEST['make'];
$req2=$_REQUEST['availability'];

mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

if ($req!="all" && $req2!="all")  $query="SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE make='$req' AND availability='$req2'";
else if($req=="all" && $req2!="all" ) $query="SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE availability='$req2'";
else if($req!="all" && $req2=="all" ) $query="SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE make='$req'";
else if($req=="all" || $req2=="all" ) $query="SELECT * FROM vehicles";

$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_query($result);
mysql_close();

$i=0;

for ($i; $i < $num; $i++){
$f12=mysql_result($result,$i,"model");
$f13=mysql_result($result,$i,"year");
$f14=mysql_result($result,$i,"availability");

echo $f12." ".$f13." ".$f14."<br />";
}
?>
```

Here is the complete code for 'config.php' which contains your database password etc:

```
<?php

$username="myUserName";
$password="myPassWord";
$database="myDatabaseName";


?>
```

Comment: This isn't the best way to do things in Wordpress, which offers its own classes to interact with the database. FWIW, if you do have to talk to MySQL directly in Wordpress, users should use PDO or MySQLi instead - the old "mysql" calls are now deprecated.